# mootools javascript template engine

Tags: javascript, mootools, template-engine

I'm using this great javascript mootools template engine: https://github.com/tbela99/template

My template looks like this:

```
var tmpl = '<ul>' + 
                 '{repeat:products}' + 
                      '<li class="small">' +
                        '{photos.0.name}' +
                        '{name}' +
                      '</li>' +
                  '{/repeat:products}' + 
          '</ul>';
```

My data below:

```
var data = {"products":[{"id":"449","name":"Apple","photos":[{"name":"image.jpg"}]}]};
new Element('div',{'html':template.substitute(tmpl,data)}).inject(document.body);
```

And my question:

How to add custom modifier (.addModifier function) inside current context `{repeat:products}` and pass a value: `{photos.0.name}` ?

For example: `{repeat:products}{customtag photos.0.name}{/repeat:products}`.
Thanks!

Comment: you should ask Thiery Bela directly, this is too dsl. his nickname on twitter is @tbela99 and he's usually quite quick to respond. having said that, there is no requirement to actually use his templating engine because it's for MooTools - I like using rivets.js for that and bi-directional data binding and it works fine. you have evaluated expressions, custom binders and formatters to use in anything, including loops. http://rivetsjs.com/ - 3.4k (+some ES5 shims). when your data changes, your template re-renders also.

Comment: Do you know if tempojs (tempojs.com) is support data bindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modifier first argument is the current object in the loop :-)

Comment: Nice that you joined Stackoverflow and answer here Thierry! `+1`